# load specific div from external website in another domain into iframe

Tags: iframe, html, loading

I've seen there are several ways to do it WHEN the websites are in the same domain, but this is not my case and, since I'm much more a designer than a programmer, I'd go as far as to ask for the simplest, most straight-forward process.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use a server-side script to parse the remote site, thereby degrading gracefully if there's any Javascript problems on the client-side and giving you control over the environment when you're parsing the remote site.

You could, e.g. write a php script to return just the relevant div, and then point the iframe straight at that.

What language / framework were you thinking of using?

Comment: Well, I was thinking of using HTML and jQuery, if possible. I am quite comfortable with those two, PHP still eludes me, but I'm always willing to learn!